# How to include a Mongodb $lookup as an Spring @Query("")

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to perform a query using an association mapped as a DBRef

What I'm trying to find is a way to search for Tickets assigned to an specific user by login name (I don't know the id)

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User  {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String login;
}

@Document(collection = "ticket")
public class Ticket  {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    @Field("assignedTo")
    private User assignedTo;

}
```

I can query by id using the following format, but the information I have is the login name so it doesn't work..

```
@Query("{'assignedTo': { '$ref' : 'user', '$id' : ?#{principal.username} } }")
Page<Ticket> findByAssignedToIsCurrentUser(Pageable pageable);
```

Can I include $lookup for the user.login in this query, ideally in a @Query annotation?

I would prefer to add it as an annotation rather than programatically or to perform and extra query..

It's there a format to include this inside the @Query("")?

Comment: $lookup is a atge of aggregation, not usable in find (@Query) query.

Comment: thanks, that explains why I could find any information about.. thank you